# What statistic to use to measure the uncertainty in the peak of a skewed distribution?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, skewness

*Disclaimer: I am not a statistician. I am not sure if this problem is incredibly easy or incredibly hard.*

I have a very large skewed empirical distribution of values which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to measure the peak of this empirical distribution along with some sort of measure of the uncertainty of the peak value (e.g. an unbalanced +/- confidence interval). In the above example it might be something like: Maximum value of 0.23 with 95% CI [0.20 0.53].

What is the best method for doing this? I've read some things about bootstrapping the mean or the median but I am not interested in the mean or median (I am interested in the peak probability of the distribution).

Note that this dataset has about 14 million points, so computational limitations should be considered. Also note that the modelled parameter is bounded on (0,1).

Comment: You could look at using a [bootstrap](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-generate-bootstrap-statistics-in-r/). In your case, you'd repeatedly sample from your data (with replacement), calculating the mode each time (say 1,000 times), then get the upper and lower bounds (95% CI) of the 1,000 samples. However, since you have 14 million data points, this would be (1) computationally taxing and (2) your confidence interval would be tiny. I think given the sheer volume of data points, there's probably not a great deal of practical use in reporting a confidence interval?